# Canvas save() and restore() not working well

Tags: canvas

The ellipse colour order (from left to right) should be red, yellow, black, yellow and red.
here's the code http://liveweave.com/Jq2xhr

What my save and restore went wrong??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing went wrong with save and restore.
The issue is that since you didn't use beginPath for each arc, everytime you call fill() you are re-filling your arcs with the new colour.
Your third circle gets filled black, then yellow and finally red again.
This should fix it.

```js
/* Write JavaScript here */
var canvas=document.getElementById('m');
var ctx=canvas.getContext('2d');

//儲存canvas會存在Stack內。Stack特性是最後儲存的數值會最先顯示，所以如果呼叫restore方法，會顯示最近的描繪狀態，在呼叫一次的話就會顯示之前的狀態。//

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.fillStyle="red";
ctx.arc(80, 80, 50, 0, Math.PI*2, true);//arc(x,y,r,starAngle, endAngle,  anticlockwise)   
ctx.fill();
ctx.save();

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.fillStyle="yellow";
ctx.arc(210, 80, 50, 0, Math.PI*2, true);
ctx.fill();
ctx.save();

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.fillStyle="#000000";
ctx.arc(340, 80, 50, 0, Math.PI*2, true);
ctx.fill();

ctx.restore();
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(470,80, 50, 0, Math.PI*2, true);
ctx.fill();


ctx.beginPath();
ctx.restore();
ctx.arc(600, 80, 50, 0, Math.PI*2, true);
ctx.fill();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>使用save和restore繪製圖形</title>
</head>
<body>
<!-- Start your code here -->

<p class="lw"></p>
  <canvas id="m" width="1000" height="200"></canvas>
<!-- End your code here -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Upvote for good catch about `beginPath`. But note that `save` and `restore` are expensive operations because they save & restore every property in the context--and context has many properties.  A more efficient plan is to save the original `fillStyle` in a variable at the top of the snippet (`var originalFill = ctx.fillStyle`) and then reset the fillStyle at the end of the snippet (`ctx.fillStyle=originalFill`). This eliminates the expensive saves / restores entirely. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

In case it helps others landing here from a web search, take note of how `ctx.restore()` works:

> The `ctx.restore()` method of the Canvas 2D API restores the most recently saved canvas state by popping the top entry in the drawing state stack. If there is no saved state, this method does nothing.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/restore

The mistake I was making was in assuming that I could simply `ctx.save()` once, and then `ctx.restore()` many times from that single save. But this (counterintuitively) is not how save/restore works. Every time you call `ctx.restore()`, it "uses up" the save, and so if you want to use that save again in the future you need to immediately call `ctx.save()` right after calling `ctx.restore()`. So if your problem/misunderstanding is like mine, then you can solve it by simply changing all instances of this:

```js
ctx.restore();
```

to this:

```js
ctx.restore();
ctx.save();
```

Comment: Yeah, it's more like "push" and "pop" than "save" and "restore".